# How do I keep mentions when using clean_content?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm getting random messages from the cache but I would like to keep the mentions from being cleaned. How do I do that?

I see [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=content%20clean#discord.ext.commands.clean_content) option in the doc but I don't know how to use that. Instead I use [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content)

This is my current code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
                
    random_message = random.choice([cached_message for cached_message
                                                in client.cached_messages])

    if message.author != client.user:
        await message.channel.send(random_message.clean_content)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not just not use `Message.clean_content` and instead just plain `Message.content`?

Comment: omg that fixed it I feel so stupid

Answer (score 0):

`message.content` is the answer. `message.clean_content` does something completely different than what I wanted